# How can I get a var within a class to be altered by a method of the same class?

Tags: swift, class, methods, var

I have the following code:

```
class QuizQuestions {
    
    var gender = "it"
    
    func chooseGender(genderButton: String) {
        if genderButton == "Female" {
            gender = "she" }
        print(gender)
    }
    
    lazy var questions = ["Does \(gender) run?", "Is \(gender) fun?"]
    
}
```

The function takes as an input the text of a UIButton. What I want is for, when the genderButton is pressed, the var gender to be updated to "she", and for that to be reflected in the 'questions' array.
The print statement in the method shows me that 'gender' is now 'she', however printing 'question[0]' will still print "Does it run?", not "Does she run?"

Why is this, and how can I make it work? TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change `questions` to be a computed property, then it will always use the current value of `gender`.

```
var questions: [String] { 
    ["Does \(gender) run?", "Is \(gender) fun?"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - this is solving the issue, however not in the way I anticipated. It seems like now, 'does she run?' is indeed computed, but only for the single instance that the UIButton is pressed. Otherwise, gender reverts to "it". Is there a way by which, once the button is pressed, var gender will retain the new value of "she" throughout the struct, every time?

Comment: @JakeJake it seems like you are having an issue outside of `QuizQuestions` itself, most probably around how you are storing/accessing `QuizQuestions` from your button(s). Without seeing more context (preferably in the form of a [mcve]), it is quite hard to help with this new issue.

Comment: no worries - appreciate the help anyway